# How to move children elements into their respective grandparents elements

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and am playing around with it to get myself familiarized with this famous framework. I like the "declarative" nature of jquery's selector in which it can grab a bunch of elements and do something to them without the explicit need to loop through each of the matched elements, much like SQL. While exploring jquery, I give myself scenarios/challenges and see if I could solve them to test my understanding. Here's one problem which I'm trying to solve with preferably one line of code (the use of only one semicolon).

```
<div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my problem is like this. I have three `<div>`, one nested inside the other creating a "Grandparent - Parent - Child" relationship. I have three such arrangements as above (three Grandparents who are siblings of each other at the root).
So my question is, how do I move ALL of the children into their own RESPECTIVE Grandparent `<div>`? In other words, I'm trying to make the children to become the siblings of their own Parent. Illustrated below is the outcome I'm trying to achieve

```
<div>
    <div class="parent">
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="parent">
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="parent">
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Here's what I've attempted to no avail

```
$('.parent > div').appendTo($(this).parent());
```

I've even tried

```
$('.parent > div').appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
```

I think I'm abusing `$(this)` here. I couldn't figure out a way to do it with only one line without using a loop. I think I might be able to do it with .each() loop but would like to try to achieve it without. Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another sollution without a loop (maybe it is a loop in jquery itself):

```
$('.parent').after(function() {
    return $('div', this);
});
```

Comment: this is neat, although still involves two semicolon. Thanks

Comment: Better that way? `$('.parent').after(function() {return $('div', this)});`

Comment: I like this one, it's more succinct and it doesn't have an explicit loop.

Comment: I didn't know `after` could take a function. Elegant. @TwistedWhisper, this is a nice solution, but in general don't obfuscate your code for the sake of not liking `each`. Future maintainers will hunt you down and strangle you in your sleep.

Comment: @Dave I totally agree. Each isn't that bad and most of the time you don't know what jquery actually does behind the scenes. But I sill like things like that :)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to loop over them:

```
$('.parent > div').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().after(this);
});
```

You could also write:

```
$('.parent > div').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: just as I thought of abstaining from the use of a loop. But I guess sometimes we can't have the best of both worlds.
Just to satisfy my curiosity, what does my attempt `$('.parent > div').appendTo($(this).parent().parent());` do (in plain English)? Or if you could explain to me why doesn't it work, in fact it doesn't even do anything.

Comment: @TwistedWhisper: Nothing, really. `this` refers to `window`, which has no `.parent()`, so there's nothing for the `div`s to move into.

Comment: That explains much. I was under the impression that `$(this)` was referring to `$('.parent > div')`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent div').each(function(){$(this).clone().appendTo($(this).parent().parent());$(this).remove()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, every answer so far has used `each`, which is the best way to do it. But in the interests of being plain weird, here is another way which avoids explicit loops:

```
$('.parent > div').unwrap().parent().contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType===3}).wrap('<div class="parent">');
```

(it does loop a lot internally, and `filter` is a loop, but jQuery doesn't have a built-in way to get text nodes)

Comment: an interesting method to explore how jquery works albeit a much verbose one =)

Comment: @TwistedWhisper, well you set the challenge of not using `each`!

Comment: Challenge accepted, have a look at my answer for another sollution without each ;)